# How to highlight rows of extended datatable when mouse is over in jsf?

Tags: javascript, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I am trying to do highlight the rows of the extended datatable when mouse is over. Here is my datatable:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable onrowmouseover ="this.style.backgroundColor='#B5F3FB'" onrowmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'" value="#{moneyTransferManager.allAccounts}" var="accounts"
                                        selection="#{extTableSelectionBean.selection}" id="table" frozenColumns="2"
                                        style="height:170px; width:484px;">
                    <a4j:ajax execute="@form" event="selectionchange" listener="#{extTableSelectionBean.selectionListener}"
                              render=":res"/>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Hesaplarım"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:column width="120px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Hesap Numarası"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{accounts.accountNumber}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="120px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Para Birimi"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{accounts.accountCurrency}"/>
                    </rich:column>                        
                </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

This one highlights only if row is clicked. Then i tried  the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("tr").not(':first').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
  }, 
  function () {
     $(this).css("background","");
  }
);

</script>
```

But this time when mouse is over, all of the rows are highlighted. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Edit:  This time i tried that javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("tr").not(':first').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).css("background", "yellow");
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).css("background", "");
                }
        );
    })
</script>
```

But still, when the mouse is on one row, every rows are highlighted. What am i doing wrong here?

Edit 2:  I also tried this:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable onrowmouseover ="this.style.backgroundColor='#B5F3FB'" onrowmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'"
```

this time it works, but when mouse is on 1st or 2nd column, first 2 are highlighted and when mouse is on 3rd or 4th colum, the 3th and 4th rows are highlighted together, i mean 1-2 are highlighted together and 3-4 are together

Here is the full code of the page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div>
        <ui:include src="/template.xhtml" />
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; top: 120px; left: 300px">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:form>


                <rich:extendedDataTable  value="#{moneyTransferManager.allAccounts}" var="accounts"
                                         selection="#{extTableSelectionBean.selection}" id="table" frozenColumns="2"
                                         style="height:170px; width:484px;">
                    <a4j:ajax execute="@form" event="selectionchange" listener="#{extTableSelectionBean.selectionListener}"
                              render=":res"/>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Hesaplarım"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:column width="120px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Hesap Numarası"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{accounts.accountNumber}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="120px;">
                        `enter code here`<f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Para Birimi"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{accounts.accountCurrency}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="120px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="IBAN"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{accounts.iban}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="120px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Bakiye"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{accounts.balance}"/>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:extendedDataTable>
            </h:form>
            <a4j:outputPanel id="res">
                <rich:panel header="Seçilen Hesap:" rendered="#{not empty extTableSelectionBean.selectionItems}">
                    <rich:list type="unordered" value="#{extTableSelectionBean.selectionItems}" var="sel">
                        <h:outputText value="#{sel.accountCurrency} - #{sel.iban} - #{sel.balance}"/>
                    </rich:list>
                </rich:panel>
            </a4j:outputPanel>



            <rich:panel styleClass="top">
                <div style="position: relative; left: -3px; top: 23px">
                    <h:outputText style=" font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; " value="Yapmak istediğiniz işlem .."></h:outputText>  
                </div>
                <h:form>
                    <div style="position: relative; left: 160px; top: -3px">
                        <rich:select value="#{transactionManager.selection}" defaultLabel="Bir işlem seçin...">
                            <f:selectItem  itemValue="0" itemLabel="Hesap Hareketlerini Listele" />  
                        </rich:select>    

                    </div>
                    <div style="position: relative; left: 380px; top: -22px">
                        <h:commandButton action="#{transactionManager.accountActivity()}" value="Devam" style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; width: 70px; height: 21px; background-color: grey; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 15px;"></h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </h:form>  
            </rich:panel>



        </h:panelGrid>

    </div>


</h:body>


</html>
```

Comment: How about using CSS pseudo classes ? `tr:hover`

Comment: @Andy thanks i will search for it, by the way can you also give me a ?link if you have

Comment: Sure one sec. Keep in mind though it doesn't work for all browsers.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Also this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: @Andy i tried hover with the js code in my edit part in the question, but still all rows are highlighted at the same time

Comment: I figured. Let me give see what I can come up with. check back in 30

Comment: thanks i will  be here

Comment: Wait, you said js code. I meant pure CSS, no javascript. Does it have to be with javascript ?

Comment: @Andy no it does not have to be a js, i have made another edit i think i am close to the end :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `onrowmouseover` and `onrowmouseout` worked fine on my end. Try using `rowClass` attribute of `<rich:extendedDataTable>` and define a rule in your stylesheet like so.

```
.test:hover {
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

And do

```
<rich:extendedDataTable  rowClass="test">
```

Remember to set your `<h:outputStylesheet>` in `<h:head>`

Comment: same thing happening again, i think it is about the richfaces and extended datatable

Comment: Same thing again ? ok, let me see what's going on with extended table.

Comment: all rows are highlighted together, weird

Comment: @iceface What version of richfaces are using ?

Comment: i am using version 4.0

Comment: @iceface Do me a favor, look at the generated html code and tell me if `table` has a class name. What is it ? I'm looking at the showcase but I want to make sure. Is it `rf-edt-tbl`

Comment: It is something like that:  <div id="j_idt73:table" class="rf-edt"

Comment: @iceface Try one more thing. If it doesn't work I'm going to download it and see for myself. change tr:hover to table.rf-edt tr:hover

Comment: this time nothing is hghlighted, i wish i am not doing a silly mistake

Comment: @iceface I have another solution hold on one sec

Comment: @iceface you're not doing a mistake. Same thing is happening to me. Why are these things never easy :). Let me see what I can find out.

Comment: Did you try <rich:extendedDataTable onrowmouseover ="this.style.backgroundColor='#B5F3FB'" onrowmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='white'"   This time columns 1 and 2 are highlighted together, and 3-4 are together

Comment: @iceface yeah, that's what I'm looking at now.

Comment: @iceface want to see sample code. I don't know why it's not working for you. Make sure you take out the js script reference

Comment: here you can see my full code:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11736122/myaccounts.xhtml

Comment: @iceface It's not downloading.

Comment: @iceface k, sorry. I tried two browsers and it's showing a blank screen.

Comment: @iceface You mind sending the beans ? I want to run it and see what's going on.

Comment: maybe in your table, since there is 1 column it is okay, but i have 4 columns, and 2 of them are not highlighted, weird :)

Comment: @iceface. Maybe. let me try.

Comment: @iceface hey, try this. Wrap each `rich:column` inside a `rich:columnGroup`

Comment: i sent the beans, but i think there are also some classes used in that beans and i need to send whole project, which has a lot of libraries and lots of dependencies in it and it will be har to work it on your computer and about 30mb. What i do here is that simply have a table with 4 columns, and fill those from the database

Comment: @iceface I noticed. Not a problem. I'll simply hardcode string. I just need an idea that's all. We will figure this out :)

Comment: i wish so :) i am going to open another question also just about the onrowmouseover thing

Comment: @iceface wait I know why it's selecting two. and it's working fine for me. Hold before you do that. I'm checking something quick.

Comment: @iceface nevermind, it's working for me. I'll update my sample but it's working perfectly.

Comment: @iceface You don't have to delete it. It's working on my end even with 4 columns. So I'm not sure what's wrong with yours.

Comment: @iceface. I have another solution

Comment: @iceface, I hope so too. If not I'm at a lost.

Comment: @iceface Take out all js reference to your code also to make sure css rule and js are not overlapping. For instance, `<h:outputScript>` try to remove and just leave the CSS.

Comment: @iceface remember to take out the `onmouse` functions also.

Comment: i solved it in a weird way, i need 4 columns for my table, since first 2 columns are problematic and are highlighted together only, i copied them and pasted them again, but i deleted the content of the first two columns and made them 0px, there are only h:column tags but inside is empty. Now the last 4 columns are highlighted together, and since first 2 columns are empty and 0px they are not seen in the table. Weird but it works fine :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @iceface Weird. So you had an extra CSS conflict. Not a problem. Glad you solved it.